# Creating a testing infrastructure with Pytest , Selenium Grid and Docker

Tags: selenium, docker, pytest, dockerfile, docker-compose

Based on this [article](http://www.conductor.com/nightlight/running-selenium-grid-using-docker-compose/), I successfully created the scalable selenium grid .
Then I want to run my test suites [written in Python] using Pytest into that Grid.

I am new to Docker and trying to find the best way to migrate my testing procedures into the microservices architecture. Essentially I want to give the ability to the devs to setup a full testing infrastructure locally on their PCs.

So, I have 4 *Dockerfiles* and 1 *docker-compose.yml* .

The BASE dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV SEL_VERSION 2.44.0

# Update repos for Java
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
software-properties-common \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java

RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections

# Install Java7
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
oracle-java7-installer \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download Selenium Server
RUN wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/${SEL_VERSION%.*}/selenium-server-standalone-${SEL_VERSION}.jar
```

The HUB dockerfile :

```
FROM org/grid:base

EXPOSE 4444

# Add and set permissions to the script that will launch the hub
ADD register-hub.sh /var/register-hub.sh
RUN chmod 755 /var/register-hub.sh

# start a shell and run the script
#WORKDIR /
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/var/register-hub.sh"]
```

The NODE dockerfile :

```
FROM org/grid:base

# set the FF version to use
ENV FIREFOX_MINOR 34.0.5

# Update and install what's needed
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
firefox \
xvfb \
bzip2 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# setup FF
RUN [ -e /usr/bin/firefox ] && rm /usr/bin/firefox
ADD https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/${FIREFOX_MINOR}/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-${FIREFOX_MINOR}.tar.bz2 /tmp/
RUN apt-get install -q -y libdbus-glib-1-2
RUN tar -xvjf /tmp/firefox-${FIREFOX_MINOR}.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
RUN chmod -R +x /opt/firefox/
RUN ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

# add and set permissions for the bash script to register the node
ADD register-node.sh /var/register-node.sh
RUN chmod 755 /var/register-node.sh

# start a shell and run the script
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/var/register-node.sh"]
```

And the PYTEST dockerfile :

```
# Starting from base image
FROM ubuntu

# Set the Github personal token [to clone the QA code]
#todo------secret------
ENV GH_TOKEN some_token_some_token_some_token_

# Install Python & pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip python-dev && pip install --upgrade pip

# Install GIT
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git -y

# [in the / folder] Create the folder and add the whole project from the repo to the container
RUN git clone https://$GH_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/org_QA.git /org_QA_folder

# Install dependencies via pip
WORKDIR /org_QA_folder
RUN pip install -r dependencies.txt

#
CMD /bin/bash
```

And the docker-compose file :

```
hub:
  image: org/grid:hub # image must already exist
  ports:
    - "4444:4444" # HOST:CONTAINER
  external_links: # link to a container created outside of this YAML file
    - pytest
  volumes_from:
    - pytest # must be created first

firefox:
  image: org/grid:nodeff # image must already exist
  links:
    - hub
  expose:
    - "5555" # grid console open to public
```

So...I cannot understand how should I run something like "py.test /org_QA_folder/testcase.py" and run on the grid [essentially the node].

I first run the pytest container  with 
`docker run -dit -v /org_QA_folder --name pytest schoox/grid:py` and the other services with `docker-compose up -d` .

I tried multiple approaches:

1. Not use a Pytest container but clone the code in the hub. But in this case , HUB container runs the hub of the grid [one CMD per container directive] . **[EDIT: I chose the microservices architecture as Docker suggests]**
2. I leave the hub and node containers to run their specified services, and create a separate container [pytest] to send the tests from there. But the test wont run cause this container does not have xvfb.**[EDIT: I just installed xvfb and worked]**
3. I tried to use the pytest container as volume for the hub but remains the problem of running the tests from the hub container that already has a service running.**[EDIT: For dev purposes I mount the code from the pytest container and use its console to test stuff on the other containers. After that I will use the pytest container to have the code separate]**

Should I install all the packages ,that node container has, in the other containers? Ideally I want to use the pytest container console [to develop the infrastructure at least] to run the tests which will be sent to hub and run to many nodes.**[EDIT: I didn't mingled with the hub and node, I just installed xvfb on pytest container]**

How would you suggest to do that? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT [steps towards solution]:**

I first start the pytest container [`docker run -dit -v /org/org_QA_folder --name pytest org/grid:py`] and then I run `docker-compose up -d` to launch the grid

In the compose file I use `external_links` and `volumes_from` for dev purposes. I wont work from inside any container when the setup is finished.

I changed the Pytest dockerfile and added this:

```
# Install xvfb [THAT WAS NEEDED!!!!!]
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
```

I run one of my tests ,from inside the pytest container, to my already running Grid[on an EC2 instance] as a proof of concept and worked fine. It remains to send it to the dockerized grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it to work like this:

From my code I use this:

```
class Fixtures_docker(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self, hub_ip="http://HUB_CONTAINER_IP", hub_port=4444):
        print "--Fixtures_docker in config.py trying to run on--: %s:%s"%(hub_ip, hub_port)

        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

            self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
            self.display.start()

        if browser == "Firefox": 
            self.wd = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor=hub_ip + ':' + str(hub_port) + '/wd/hub',
                    desired_capabilities={
                        #FIREFOX
                        "browserName"   : "firefox",
                        # "maxInstances"  : 10,
                        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
                        "platform"      : "ANY",
                        "node"          : hub_port
                })

        # for debugging purposes from local machine
        elif browser == "Firefox" and os == "Windows":
            self.wd = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor=hub_ip + ':' + str(hub_port) + '/wd/hub',
                    desired_capabilities={
                        # FIREFOX -> WINDOWS
                        # "firefox_binary":"C:\\firefox3\Firefox3.exe", # path to find another version of ff
                        "browserName"   : "firefox",
                        #"version"      : "3.0b3", # trying to run a specific ff version
                        "platform"      : "WINDOWS",
                        "node"          : hub_port,
                        "maxSession"    : 5
                })

        self.wd.implicitly_wait(10)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.wd.quit()
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            self.display.stop()
```

and in the docker-compose.yml:

```
hub:
  image: org/grid:hub # image must already exist
  ports:
    - "8080:4444" # HOST:CONTAINER
  external_links: # link to a container created outside of this YAML file
    - pytest
  volumes_from:
    - pytest # must be created first
  expose:
    - "4444" # intercontainer communication [other containers with selenium server]

firefox:
  image: org/grid:nodeff # image must already exist
  links:
    - hub
  expose:
    - "5555" # intercontainer communication [node registers to hub]
```

Comment: so you switched from pytest to unittest? why? would pytest not work at all?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're almost there.

I would add a `pytest` service to the `docker-compose.yml`, and remove the `volumes_from` and `external_links` from the `hub` image (so that it looks more like the example from the blog post you linked).

The `pytest` service will run the python code, but it should connect to hub to run selenium. I believe somewhere in  the `org_QA_folder` there is configuration that tries to start up selenium locally. It needs to be reconfigured to use the `hub` server instead.

Comment: I use that format [external links/volumes_from] temporarily until I setup the whole pipeline. Indeed, I have a config file in the code with this [https://gist.github.com/wehappyfew/3430d1aa044c8ebc3d52] in it. I tested it with the IP/port of the Grid I already have on an ec2 instance and worked fine. I understood that I must do the same thing with this Docker grid...but what I am confused about, is how the services from 2 containers talk to each other.Which IPs/ports should I use? I should point webdriver [RemoteDriver] to the container[172.17.0.3:port] or the host[ec2__public_IP:8080] ?

Comment: Neither, use the service name as the hostname (ex: `hub:4444`, or `firefox:5555`).  These values are made available by docker-compose and docker.